# Identity in ractive data arrays

Tags: ractivejs

I have an object of message streams that looks like this:

ractive.data.messages:

```
{
    stream_id1: {
        some_stream_metadata: "foo",
        stream: [  
            {id: "someid1", message: "message1"}, 
            {id: "someid2", message: "message2"}
        ]
    },
    stream_id2: {
        some_stream_metadata: "bar",
        stream: [
            {id: "someid3", message: "message3"},
            {id: "someid4", message: "message4"}
        ]
    }
}
```

main_template:

```
{{#messages[ current_stream_id ]}}
    {{>render_message_stream}}
{{/messages[ current_stream_id ]}}
```

render_message_stream:

```
{{#stream}}
    <div class="stream">
    ...someotherstuff...
        {{>render_message}}
    </div>
{{/stream}}
```

render_message:

```
<div class="message">
...someotherstuff...
    {{message}}
</div>
```

I change "current_stream_id" to change the rendered stream of messages.

On updates, i change the contents of the message streams like this:

```
ractive.merge(
    "messages.stream_id1.stream",
    new_message_stream,
    {
        compare: function ( item ) { return item.id; }
    });
```

I also tried the compare: true option instead of the function, with the same results:

Ractive always thinks that these two messages belong effectively to the same DOM element, even though they live in a completely different message stream:

```
ractive.data.messages[ "stream_id1" ].stream[1].message
ractive.data.messages[ "stream_id2" ].stream[1].message
```

Problems:

- When there are intro/outro animations ractive animates always just the end of the messages stream, even when a message in the middle of the stream was deleted, i need help to make ractive understand which messages are identical.
- When i change the current_stream_id, ractive does not rerender the complete  {{>render_message_stream}} partial, but goes inside the existing dom and changes the {{message}} field in all existing messages, though this might be good for dom element reuse, this triggers a lot of animations that are wrong. (Eg. it triggers intro/outro animations for the last message in the stream if stream1 has one message more than stream2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these issues has a straightforward answer; unfortunately the other one doesn't.

I'll start with the easy one - the fact that

```js
ractive.data.messages[ "stream_id1" ].stream[1].message
ractive.data.messages[ "stream_id2" ].stream[1].message
```

belong to the same DOM element. You're correct in that Ractive updates the existing elements rather than removing them and creating new ones - this is a core part of its design. In this case that's undesirable behaviour, but you can work around it like so:

```js
// instead of immediately switching to a new stream ID like this...
ractive.set( 'current_stream_id', 'stream_id2' );

// you can set it to a non-existent ID. That will cause the existing DOM
// to be removed. When you set it to an ID that *does* exist, new DOM
// will be created:
ractive.set( 'current_stream_id', null );
ractive.set( 'current_stream_id', 'stream_id2' );

// or, if you'd like the initial transitions to complete first...
ractive.set( 'current_stream_id', null ).then(function () {
  ractive.set( 'current_stream_id', 'stream_id2' );
});
```

The other issue - that `merge()` isn't merging, but is instead behaving as though you were doing `ractive.set('messages.stream_id1.stream', new_message_stream)` - is tougher. The problem is that while you and I know that `{{#messages[ current_stream_id ]}}` equates to `messages.stream_id1` when `current_stream_id === 'stream_id1`, *Ractive doesn't*.

What it does know is that we have an *expression* whose value is determined by `messages` and `current_stream_id`. When the value of either of those references changes, the expression is re-evaluated, and if *that* value changes, the DOM gets updated - but using a standard `set()`. When you do `ractive.merge('messages.stream_id1.stream', ...)`, Ractive updates all the things that depend on keypaths that are 'upstream' or 'downstream' of `messages.stream_id1.stream` - which includes `messages`. So that's how the expression knows that it needs to re-evaluate.

It's possible that a future version of Ractive will be able to handle this case in a smarter fashion. Perhaps it could make a note of arrays that are subject to merge operations, and check evaluator results to see if they're identical to one of those arrays, and if so use `merge()` rather than `set()`. Perhaps it could analyse the function in some way to see if the `{{#messages[ current_stream_id ]}}` section should register itself as a dependant of `messages.stream_id1` for as long as `current_stream_id === 'stream_id1'`, rather than the internally-generated `${messages-current_stream_id-}` keypath.

None of that helps you in the meantime though. The only way to use `merge()` in your current  situation is to have a separate reference that doesn't use an expression, and a bit of magic with *pattern observers*:

**main_template:**

```
{{#current_messages}} <!-- rather than `messages[ current_stream_id ]` -->
    {{>render_message_stream}}
{{/current_messages}}
```

**render_message_stream:**

```
{{#current_message_stream}} <!-- rather than `stream` -->
    <div class="stream">
        {{>render_message}}
    </div>
{{/current_message_stream}}
```

**code:**

```js
ractive.observe( 'current_stream_id', function ( id ) {
    var current_messages = this.get( 'messages.' + id );

    this.set( 'current_messages', current_messages );

    // hide existing stream, then show new stream
    this.set( 'current_message_stream', null ).then(function () {
        this.set( 'current_message_stream', current_messages.stream );
    });
});

// when ANY message stream changes, we see if it's the current one - if so, we
// perform a merge on the top-level `current_message_stream` array
ractive.observe( 'messages.*.stream', function ( new_stream, old_stream, keypath, id ) {
    // the value of any * characters are passed in as extra arguments, hence `id`

    if ( id === this.get( 'current_stream_id' ) ) {
        this.merge( 'current_message_stream', new_stream, {
            compare: function ( item ) {
                return item.id;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/BzQ9f/) demonstrating this. I hope it makes sense, let me know if not - and sorry I didn't get round to answering this question much sooner.

Comment: For later reference: with latest Ractive, `var id_of_changed_stream = /messages\.([^\.]+)\.stream/.exec( keypath )[1];` line is not necessary, the id matching the wildcard * in `messages.*.stream` will be passed as an additional argument to the callback. See bottom paragraph of [Pattern Observers](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/observers) for more details.